# Libgdx Android: Commas and dots not showing

Tags: libgdx

I'm using a `FreeTypeFont` where I set the parameter size and also scale the font.
In desktop commas and dots are showing, e.g. "1.000.000" but when I run it in Android it becomes "1 000 000"

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by setting the maximu texture size.

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator.setMaxTextureSize(2048)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the default Texture filters can cause small images to disappear, try this:

```java
font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
```